# Recycler View doesn't scroll smoothly

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have implemented the following `RecyclerViewAdapter` with a `LinearLayoutManager`

```
class WaterSummaryListAdapter(private var dataList: List<WaterSummaryListItem>): RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.list_row_water_summary,
                        parent,
                        false)
        return ItemViewHolder(v)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = dataList.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder?, position: Int) {
        val dataItem = dataList[position]

        if (holder is ItemViewHolder){
            holder.update(dataItem)
        }
    }

    inner class ItemViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        private var date = itemView.itemDateSummaryList
        private var value = itemView.waterValue

        fun update(item: WaterSummaryListItem){
            this.date.text = item.date
            this.value.text = item.volume.toString()
        }

    }

    fun changeValueOf(itemNo: Int, value: Float){
        dataList[itemNo].volume = value
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

but when it comes to scrolling, it doesn't scroll smoothly. It get's suddenly stopped. I even tried `.setHasFixedSize(true)` but even that doesn't work.

```
recyclerView = view.summaryListRecyclerView
val manager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
adapter = WaterSummaryListAdapter(mSummaryListItems)
recyclerView.layoutManager = manager
recyclerView.adapter = adapter
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
```

Above is how I implemented the adapter to recycler view.

Comment: have you assigned a LayoutManager to your RecyclerView? If not that's probably the issue

Comment: Share your code for activity also

Comment: @YoLo I have edited the question.

Comment: your LinearLayoutManager does not provide a scroll direction, try like this: LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL/HORIZONTAL, false)

Comment: Everything should work smooth here, maybe there is another beast in background? What is your device, setup?

Comment: @PietroScarampella default constructor of LinearLayoutManager:  public LinearLayoutManager(Context context) {
        this(context, VERTICAL, false);
    }

Comment: @ViktorYakunin ups, didn't check it out! Sorry!

Comment: Are you setting any custom font to the textview?

Comment: @ViktorYakunin My view is seperated to two. Top part is graph from a custom graph library and the bottom is the recycler view. Is it the problem? Something from the graph view affects the recycler view performance?

Comment: @Fathimakm nope.

Comment: Jerky scrolling is occurring due to the layout issue. please post your xml code.

Comment: @kokilayaa the graph lib can be the problem if it does a lot of work in onDraw() method and something causes re-draw of the graph all the time. Do you have same issue if you disable the graph view?

Comment: You can consider using this. No boilerplate code, no performance problems. https://github.com/burakeregar/EasiestGenericRecyclerAdapter

Comment: @ViktorYakunin I'll try. But the graph library draws only one time right? Lag in the scroll keeps all the time. Sometimes it scroll down perfectly but then again when it comes to scrolling up it lags. Sometimes lag both ways. Graph view and the recycler view are both in one scroll view one after the other.

Comment: @kokilayaa so you said, that you have recyclerView inside scrollview? can you add your layout and some code how it works together. Seems that we found the root of the problem

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your layout as given below

```
recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity, LinearLayout.VERTICAL, false)
recyclerView.adapter = MyAdapter(yourList)
```

Comment: the most stupid answer ever, go to default constructor :  public LinearLayoutManager(Context context) {
        this(context, VERTICAL, false);
    }

Answer (score 0):

Write light weight code in `holder.update(dataItem)` method body

Comment: Isn't the already existing code light weight? I'm just setting the text of the textview there.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the if condition in onBindViewHolder and call update method directly

> if (holder is ItemViewHolder){}

```
holder.update(dataItem)
```

Comment: Tried but doesn't make any change.

Answer (score 0):

> you can use SpeedyLinearLayoutManager

```
SpeedyLinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new SpeedyLinearLayoutManager(this);
        linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        Adapter myAdapter = new Adapter(myContext);
        myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        myRecyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);



public class SpeedyLinearLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {

        private static final float MILLISECONDS_PER_INCH = 6f; //default is 25f 
        // set the speed here 

        public SpeedyLinearLayoutManager(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        public SpeedyLinearLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
            super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
        }

        public SpeedyLinearLayoutManager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean canScrollVertically() {
            //Similarly you can customize "canScrollHorizontally()" for managing horizontal scroll
            return CommonUtils.IsContactActivityScrollEnabled && super.canScrollVertically();
        }

        @Override
        public void smoothScrollToPosition(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.State state, int position) {

            final LinearSmoothScroller linearSmoothScroller = new LinearSmoothScroller(recyclerView.getContext()) {

                @Override
                public PointF computeScrollVectorForPosition(int targetPosition) {
                    return SpeedyLinearLayoutManager.this.computeScrollVectorForPosition(targetPosition);
                }

                @Override
                protected float calculateSpeedPerPixel(DisplayMetrics displayMetrics) {
                    return MILLISECONDS_PER_INCH / displayMetrics.densityDpi;
                }
            };

            linearSmoothScroller.setTargetPosition(position);
            startSmoothScroll(linearSmoothScroller);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to change your first line,

```
class WaterSummaryListAdapter(private var dataList: List<WaterSummaryListItem>): RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>()
```

with

```
class WaterSummaryListAdapter(private var dataList: List<WaterSummaryListItem>): RecyclerView.Adapter< WaterSummaryListAdapter.ItemViewHolder>()
```

UPDATE: removed unnecessary suggestion thanks @Viktor Yakunin

Comment: top statement is true, but second is not. He did it right, that is the purpose of ViewHolder - you initialize views (findViewById under the hood) once and re-use on update.

Comment: Oops. I didn't notice the initialization for those  objects.